# How to open Explorer with mouse only

Tags: windows-8

I have no issues accessing Explorer with using <kbd>Win Logo</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> but what is the alternative? Some "less skilled" with computers don't know that shortcut, how can they do it?

Comment: Go to desktop, click on folder icon pinned by default..?

Comment: Some of us remove it, and then others can't use my computer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the lower left corner of the screen (which is equivalent to pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) and click “File Explorer”:

[image: Screenshot of popup menu]

Comment: nice trick for the Win logo in keyboard-face

Comment: I always have to refer to an older post of mine to find the image again, so it's actually a pita to do :P

Comment: Beware, Joey, using images for keyboard keys [doesn't always look nice at all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K1kEX.png).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Superbar and click on the icon with the folder. It’s pinned there by default.

Comment: What's a Superbar?

Comment: To be fair... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superbar#Taskbar

Comment: @RowlandShaw Taskbar.